# Class.forName error in Java connecting to SQL Database

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm getting some kind of syntax error and I'm not sure how to resolve it or what I'm doing wrong exactly. I was following a tutorial on youtube, and I followed exactly how it was done in the video. I added the jar file to the project, but its still giving me this error. I'm fairly new to java and just trying to learn how to create a link between a java application and a sql database.

The error is on the line for:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Any help or hints is appreciated

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {

    String dbURL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB1";
    String user = "sa";
    String pass = "pass";

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    try {
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from Login");



        while (myRs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("Username"));
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("Password"));
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I haven't written anything into the main yet, what I've posted is the complete code I've done. Here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token DBConnect.java  /database_console/src/database_console  line 11 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration DBConnect.java  /database_console/src/database_console  line 11 Java Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName   DBConnect.java  /database_console/src/database_console  line 11 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName    DBConnect.java  /database_console/src/database_console  line 11 Java Problem
```

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: Do you defined the connector lib correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure you are getting the jar from the correct place: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Then, add it to your classpath. If you are using eclipse, press `CTRL+SHIFT+T` and type `SQLServerDriver`. It must find the class name.

Lastly, your code won't compile. Add the entire code you wrote inside the main method:

```
public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB1";
        String user = "sa";
        String pass = "pass";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
             Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
             ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from Login")) {

            while (myRs.next()) {
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("Username"));
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("Password"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! From the tutorials I had watched, no one was putting any of that inside the main method. That fixed it, you're the best